# How do you handle limiting coalesce requests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, json-api

Using the JSONAPI adapter.

I have two articles. In an Ember template:

```
{{#each articles as |article|}}
  {{article.comments}}
{{/each}}
```

With [coalesce](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests) enabled. If each article has a `100` comments. Ember Data will execute:

```
comments?filter[id]=1,2,3,4,5,6…200
```

The endpoint handling `comments?filter[id]` is expected to receive X amount of ids. The API endpoint is exposed to anyone trying to do:

```
comments?filter[id]=1,2,3,4,5,6…9999999
```

Which will be quite taxing on the database. How do you handle such situations?

Comment: We handle it with comments?page=1 then load more gets page=2. Never seen such approach to pagination :O

Comment: Which approach to pagination are you referring to, which you haven't seen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get all the comments for a given article, JSON API lets the server provide a `"related"` link with each article resource.

That is, if you request (e.g.) `GET /articles/1`, the server can return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": { /* data for your article */ },
    "relationships": {
      "comments": {
        "links": {
          // the uri below should all the article's comments 
          // as primary data
          "related": "http://SOME_URI_HERE..." 
        }
      }
      /* other relationships would follow ... */
    }
  }
}
```

Then, Ember Data can (I think) be told to just follow the related link to load all the comments. However, if your server doesn't support the `"related"` link, or if you really do need to find a random subset of the comments by id (with `filter[id]`), then it's just up to the server to make sure that too many ids aren't provided. (So, if more than X ids are provided, the server is allowed to respond with an error, using the JSON API error format.)